# DataSet Designer - Auto Add Columns

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dataset

in my VB.Net application I've created a Dataset that call an existing MS SQL Server stored procedure but after the wizard close no columns where added... how can I add all the columns returned by the stored procedure without adding them manually (off course the stored procedure might change in the future) in which case manually will not work.

Using VS.Net 2008

Comment: In general I've found that trying to let the users change the database structure from the application is a bad idea and the database needs to be redesigned. 

That said, you aren't giving us enough to work with here to even poitn you towards an answer. Please post the sp you are using and some examples of what you are trying to accomplish (actual data preferred).

Answer (score 0):

Not enough information to say for sure.  Can you post the procedure?

Several things to look out for, if the procedure returns a temp table or if it drops and creates a table make sure that table exists in database when you build the data set.